# Create large amount of contacts Google Contacts API V3

Tags: google-contacts-api

I need to create 1000+ contacts with Google Contacts API v3. For now, I am sending a request for every single user, and for 1000 contacts it takes almost 10 min.

Is there any better/faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Better way is by using [**Batch Operations**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#batch_operations). As mentioned in the given documentation,

> With batch requests you can have the server perform multiple operations with a single HTTP request. The basic idea is that you create a contacts or contact groups feed and add an entry for each operation you want to perform.

To send a batch request for operations on contacts, send an authorized POST request to the contacts batch feed URL with the batch feed data in the body:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/batch
```

However, please note that batch requests are limited to 100 operations at a time.

Please find more information about batch operations in the [Google Data APIs Batch Processing](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/batch) documentation.